# mod_rewrite: rewrite rule or redirect?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-redirect

If I use an internal rewrite rule to change my web page names instead of a redirect,it appears that I will have a duplication of content? For example, if I rewrite /oldpage.html to /working-person.html, it gets an internal redirect to working-person.html. This actually works. But oldpage.html is still a "direct" link, and does not show a 301.

The server throws a 500 error if I add [R] or [R=301] at the end: 
RewriteRule ^oldpage.html$ working-person.html [R=301].

On the other hand, Redirect 301 /oldpage.html hXXp://www.example.com/working-person.html works.  Should I just use a redirect?

I thought I read somewhere to use rewriterule instead of redirect when using other directives. Why use an internal rewrite if you get duplicate content?

Thanks for any ideas/opinions.

Comment: you should have tagged this question with the relevant technologies. The tags help this question to get noticed by who is able to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

That is case to case basis. On your case you should use HTTP 301 permanent redirect in order to avoid content duplication. I personally use rewrites only to make links user and SEO friendly.